# UWP XAML RadDataGrid Wrap Header Text

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik

I have a simple RadDataGrid

```
<grid:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.datarows}"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<grid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
 <grid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="testcolumn" Header="a very long header name" />
 </grid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</grid:RadDataGrid>
```

I would like to wrap the column header text, to fit within a specific width. You can specify the column width in the DataGridTextColumn headerstyle but i dont see any way of wrapping the text. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide an example of the `HeaderStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be easy.

You can do something like this :

```
 <grid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="AccessCat">
                    <grid:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                <Run Text="Access"/>
                                <LineBreak/>
                                <Run Text="cat."/>
                            </TextBlock.Inlines>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </grid:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </grid:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: This column when grouped throws exception "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No installed components were detected." . Please provide alternative solution to wrap header text of Column. Thanks in advance.